# Excel formula to copy data adjacent to a cell and paste it next to a duplicate cell in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want help in excel,

In the table mentioned below I want to look for duplicates in columns C and A and assign the value from D to B as per the data in A when compared to C.

***Problem:***
[image]

Must look like after formula:
***Solution:***

[image]

Comment: SO is literally littered with questions/problems like these. Have a look around, do you research before posting questions (or at least include your own attempt) to make this on topic.

Comment: @JvdV already did the research, would be really helpful if you can submit a link to a duplicate question, If found, I will delete this one. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: There will be so many. Just search on SO, I'll link a few. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14778586/9758194) for example. Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23062008/9758194) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14778551/9758194) etc. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ***Microsoft365***, `XLOOKUP()` is best option like-

```
=XLOOKUP(A1,$C$1:$C$4,$D$1:$D$4,"")
```

For older version you can use `INDEX/MATCH` or `VLOOKUP()` in this way.

```
=INDEX($D$1:$D$4,MATCH(A1,$C$1:$C$4,0))
=VLOOKUP(A1,$C$1:$D$4,2,FALSE)
```

Another option is to use `FILTER()` function.

```
=@FILTER($D$1:$D$4,$C$1:$C$4=A1,"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
=INDEX(B1:Bxxx,MATCH(C1,A1:Axxx,0))
```

If there is no match, you will get N/A.

[image]